# How can I change a SEF URL to display another template?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, k2, url, sef

I am using Joomla 3.3 and K2 v2.6.9.

I have a category view with several items, namely books. The URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&task=category&id=214:publikationen&Itemid=203
```

To present these items in a CSV-style list, I need to use another template, called `csv-view`. So I create the link to this view by this code::

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>&amp;template=csv-view
```

resulting in this URL:

```
http://localhost/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&task=category&id=214:publikationen&Itemid=203&template=csv-view
```

This works.

But when I activate SEF URL the URL changes to

```
http://localhost/navigation/forschung/itemlist/category/214-publikationen.html
```

and the extended URL would be

```
http://localhost/navigation/forschung/itemlist/category/214-publikationen.html&template=csv-view
```

and this page can't be found.

So here is my question: how can I construct the correct URL for the CSV view even if SEF URLs are activated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Instead of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, you can rely on `JUri::root()`
2. template parameter can not be added concatenating it with `&`. It has to be `?` ... but it depends on the Url query. Thus, you need a piece of code like this to define the glue:

   ```
   $uri = JUri::getInstance($url);
   $query = $uri->getQuery();

   if (empty($query))
   {
       $glue = '?';
   }
   else
   {
       $glue = '&';
   }
   ```

As suggested by @fruppel in a more compact way:

```
    $uri = JUri::getInstance($url); 
    $uri->setVar('tmpl', 'csv-view'); 
    $url = $uri->toString();
```

Comment: You could use setVar which will automatically add a '?' or '&': $uri->setVar('tmpl', 'csv-view');