# Loading component only in fancybox window

Tags: modal

I have setup fancybox2 in my joomla3 site. It is working, but I need to display only the component area inside the window when a link is clicked. Is there a way of doing this?

My fancybox js currently is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        type: 'iframe',
        openEffect: 'elastic',
        closeEffect: 'elastic'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @subashbasnet8 pointed out, you can add `tmpl=component` to your URL. This will display your site using the file `JOOMLAROOT/templates/YOURTEMPLATE/component.php`, a template file that loads the HTML headers and your component area (as opposed to the `index.php` file that usually is loaded).

You can modify this file if needed, or you can create your own custom view by adding another `.php` file to your template directory, e.g. `JOOMLAROOT/templates/YOURTEMPLATE/customview.php`. This customized file can be used by adding `tmpl=customview` to your url.

Regarding SEF urls, take a look at [this answer](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/7312/how-can-i-change-a-sef-url-to-display-another-template/7313#7313).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to load only component in view add **tmpl=component** in url of that page you want to open.
for example:

```
     joomlasite.com/index.php?option=com_component&view=page
     (this will load whole joomla site)
```

but

```
    joomlasite.com/index.php?option=com_component&view=page&tmpl=component 
    (this will load only component part in view).
```

hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm a bit confused: is this supposed to work with sef urls? e.g /sefurl&tmpl=component

Comment: try using JRoute class while creating url for more    `<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_component&view=page&tmpl=component'); ?>`